# Length of values does not match length of index while trying to assign score

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign an RFM score in the below data-set.When i create a subset of the data, for instance the df_not1 data frame, then I could not run the scoring code, throwing an error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'cust':["a1",   "a2",   "a3",   "a4",   "a5",   "a6",   "a7",   "a8",   "a9",   "a10",  "a11",  "a12",  "a13",  "a14",  "a15",  "a16",  "a17",  "a18",  "a19",  "a20",  "a21",  "a22",  "a23",  "a24",  "a25",  "a26",  "a27",  "a28",  "a29",  "a30",  "a31",  "a32",  "a33",  "a34",  "a35",  "a36",  "a37",  "a38",  "a39",  "a40",  "a41",  "a42",  "a43",  "a44",  "a45",  "a46",  "a47",  "a48",  "a49",  "a50",  "a51"],
        'recency':[3,   7,  9,  9,  6,  8,  3,  9,  6,  5,  8,  6,  2,  8,  3,  3,  2,  7,  3,  1,  7,  6,  10, 6,  2,  8,  6,  10, 2,  7,  9,  1,  1,  3,  6,  4,  6,  4,  6,  6,  7,  3,  7,  9,  6,  4,  7,  3,  1,  9,  3],
        'frequency':[15,    9,  13, 9,  19, 1,  11, 20, 20, 15, 15, 18, 1,  9,  20, 14, 11, 11, 4,  15, 1,  8,  17, 19, 13, 20, 1,  11, 3,  8,  2,  4,  15, 5,  12, 15, 20, 6,  19, 2,  6,  12, 6,  6,  4,  7,  2,  3,  20, 13, 11],
       'monetary':[8854,    5614,   2687,   3553,   1801,   1076,   9724,   7778,   8382,   4391,   6766,   9905,   3181,   4170,   7544,   2997,   3025,   9358,   6015,   9919,   5132,   3598,   8779,   4420,   8931,   1492,   5491,   4186,   4720,   2568,   2530,   4618,   4109,   9384,   3000,   9766,   9524,   1027,   6315,   9806,   3442,   7256,   2432,   2429,   7696,   4527,   1802,   6606,   3018,   6295,   2985]}

  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1=df[df['frequency']==1]
df_not1=df[df['frequency']!=1]

rfm_df=df_not1[['recency','frequency','monetary']]

s1=np.full((1,rfm_df.shape[0]-int(0.8 * rfm_df.shape[0])),1)
s2=np.full((1,int(0.2*rfm_df.shape[0])),2)
s3=np.full((1,int(0.2*rfm_df.shape[0])),3)
s4=np.full((1,int(0.2*rfm_df.shape[0])),4)
s5=np.full((1,int(0.2*rfm_df.shape[0])),5)
score=np.hstack((s1,s2,s3,s4,s5)).flatten()

rfm_df=rfm_df.sort_values(by='recency',ascending=False)
rfm_df['r_score']=score

for i,j in zip(('frequency','monetary'),('f_score','m_score')):
    rfm_df=rfm_df.sort_values(by=i)
    rfm_df[j]=score
```

However it is not allowing to run the code as I am getting this error.

```
ValueError: Length of values (46) does not match length of index (47)
```

Comment: Okay, so what is your question about this? Also, are you able to reproduce the problem with maller input data?

Comment: Just for simplicity i have provided a sample datasets. However i am getting the same error with larger datasets.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping you could get something even smaller, and really isolate the problem. 47 elements is nothing for a computer, but it's a lot for a human to look at and consider. In the process of trying to create this example, you should hopefully discover something useful about why the data causes a problem. See also http://sscce.org.

Comment: For your information when i run the complete data set i.e df then i don't get any error. when i subset and use the subset data set, then it is giving the error

Comment: Aha, I found the problem, now that I tried to understand what the code is actually doing. Here's a hint: what is `int(0.8 * 47)`? What is `int(0.2 * 47)`? You should have looked for this yourself by tracing backward from the problem and testing your assumptions. For example, look at the full traceback and see what lengths it's talking about. Here, the `values` come from `score`, so you would first check and see that indeed has 46 values instead of 47. Why? Well, *how was it created*? Then you look at those steps.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Anyway, it's probably better if you don't use floating-point division for this, but instead integer div and mod.